# How to secure magento store with password protected with htacess?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

My site is running on the server .I want to make it password protected by using htacess but i am confused about the htacess file location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. /var/www/projectname/.htaccess

```
### password protected ###
AuthName "Protected page"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/projectname/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

> 2. /var/www/projectname/.htpasswd

```
usman:$apr1$zUikaL6j$5GClp9ADKHm8/uuhph3BI1
```

Note :

```
usman:$apr1$zUikaL6j$5GClp9ADKHm8/uuhph3BI1 = usman:usman
  |               |
username       password
```

Comment: it gives me 500 internal server error

Comment: when i check var/log/apache2/error.log it gave me an error of
[Thu Jan 16 01:51:17.608694 2020] [authn_file:error] [pid 14977] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:37804] AH01620: Could not open password file: /var/www/html/myproject.htpasswd

Comment: In `AuthUserFile "/var/www/projectname/.htpasswd"` you replace `projectname` by your Real project name

Comment: Thanks a lot my issue is resolved .i only want to know how u incrept password?

Comment: https://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: Thanku so much .you save my day

Comment: You're welcome, good luck.